# What to do with lisp code of web server to run it?

Tags: server, web

Before I was using Apache web server and Node Express but then I started to learn Emacs for the web purpose. After I found the web server code I could not start it or maybe I started it but but did not know the way to see served sites. Are the sites visible only in Emacs or also in chrome and Firefox? So I did these:
I took the code from https://eschulte.github.io/emacs-web-server/Hello-World.html#Hello-World and put it to ws.el file. I placed this file in the user home folder: `/home/user`

Then I typed in emacs `M-x load-file` `ws.el`
In the *Messages* buffer this appeared

> Loading /home/u/ws.el (source)... load-with-code-conversion: Symbol’s
> function definition is void: ws-start

I did not know if it was an error or warning.

Then I typed `M-:` `ws-start` and got this:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ws-start)
> eval-expression(ws-start nil nil 127)
> funcall-interactively(eval-expression ws-start nil nil 127)
> command-execute(eval-expression)

Then I tried to open the URL in chrome `127.0.0.1:9000` and it did not work. How to run the web server in emacs?

Comment: You should install the web server first from Elpa `M-x package-install` `web-server`, or load it if you installed it already `M-x load-library` `web-server`. Then load your ws.el file and visit localhost:9000 in your favorite web browser.

Comment: `Symbol’s function definition is void: ws-start` is indeed an error: when you loaded `ws.el`, the lisp interpreter tried to evaluate the expression in that file which calls the function `ws-start`, but it found no such definition (follow @dalanicolai's comment to resolve that).

Comment: Note also that `M-: <some-lisp-expression>` is used to evaluate the lisp expression you provide. `M-: ws-start` uses the name as a variable and tries to get the value of that variable. But there is no such variable (and there will be no such variable even after you resolve the problem above), hence the `void-variable ws-start` error message.

Comment: You should (re-)read the first two parts of the Emacs manual carefully: "Important General Concepts"
 consisting of Chapters 1-7 in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) and "Fundamental Editing Commands" consisting of Chapters 8-11 in the same manual.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one to keep and delete the other one. Thx.